# WPF binding to Grid.ColumnSpan

Tags: wpf, grid, wcf-binding

I've got two textboxes in a WPF gridview. The second one is hidden using a method on the view model (GetNoteTwoVisibility) if there is no text to display - no problem there.  In this case though I'd like to change the column span of the first text box to use both columns.  I've tried adding a 'GetNoteOneColumnSpan' method (returning an int) but this doesn't work.

```
<TextBox Name="Note1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NotesView.NoteOne}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding NotesView.GetNoteColumnSpan}" />
<TextBox Name="Note2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NotesView.NoteTwo}" Visibility="{Binding NotesView.GetNoteTwoVisibility}" />
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need another binding property for `Grid.ColumnSpan`. You could try something like:

```
<TextBox Name="Note1"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Text="{Binding NotesView.NoteOne}">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan"
              Value="1" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NotesView.GetNoteTwoVisibility}"
                      Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan"
                  Value="2" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
<TextBox Name="Note2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Text="{Binding NotesView.NoteTwo}"
          Visibility="{Binding NotesView.GetNoteTwoVisibility}" />
```

Comment: that works perfectly (once I'd remembered my Visibility method returned a Visibility enum and not a bool!), thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope you do have a reason for having System.Windows.Visibility Property in your ViewModel than use a bool value in the ViewModel and use a converter in xaml.

Comment: No reason, guess it's just how the app was written, will look into use of converters though if that's better practice, thanks

Comment: Yeh people argue on both sides saying things from System.Windows should not be in the ViewModel cos it kinda screws up testability and some argue against it for ease of use. I favor the first group lol. It isn't much extra effort with a converter since you do not have to create a BooleanToVisibility converter anyways. It's available directly